# netty 4 - Blocking the worker thread

Tags: netty

I hope somebody is able to shed some light on this. My protocol is as follows:

Clients use either a custom TCP-based text protocol, or SOAP Web-Services. Clients always have to wait for an application-level response, communication is synchronous. SOAP requests are handled via a Tomcat web application, the custom protocol requests are handled by a netty server that is started embedded in Tomcat. In my scenario, if clients time out, they resend requests as long as they do not get a response. Now I know that it is considered bad practice to do your business logic directly in the worker thread, but in the scenario outlined above:

What are the benefits of using a separate thread pool for the actual business logic? Yes, worker threads would get freed up, but that just delegates the problem to the separate "business" thread pool. It is my understanding that if the business thread pool is exhausted incoming messages would queue up and get processed eventually, when threads in the business pool are available again. But the client would time out in the meantime, resending the already processed message again, thus generating more and more load on the server. Is it advisable/ok to do the business logic directly in the worker thread in this scenario?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: This question is really opinion based, stackoverflow isn't good for these kind of questions. the advantage of a separate thread pool for your business logic is that you can increase the size of that pool if all the tasks are blocking tasks

Comment: Ok, agreed, but couldn't I do that with the worker thread pool as well? As for the question: I just want to know if I'm missing the big and obvious "do not do this because of XXX" point here.